# Why is the <a>-tag lying there at the bottom while it really surrounds the <img>?

Tags: html, css

It looks like the `<a>`-tag is visually lying at the bottom of the `<img>`-tag:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico"/>
</a>

a {
    background: #999;    
}
a:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
img {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

There is a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/d2fc1jz5/

Note: Tested in Chrome only.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jrww42jx/

Comment: @JoshCrozier, thanks it works.... but why? It is the `float:left` on the `<a>` that does it. `float:right` also works. But those floats are for the surrounding so to say, not the internal of `<a>`. ;-)

Comment: Here's one with `display: inline-block` instead of `float`. I've also fixed the missing alt text and missing focus styles (that should be applied at the same time as hover): http://jsfiddle.net/8z0002hx/

Comment: Thanks @danielnixon, that works better since it does not change my whole layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add display:inline-block to your a class like so:

```
a {
background: #999; 
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You were first to make it an answer (and `vertical-align` is not needed). I actually tried that first, but it failed. The reason seems to be that I have an extra `<span>` inside the `<a>` around the `<img>`. Quite tricky.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 2):

Change your CSS style like this. All I have changed is added display:inline-block to the 'a' selector and vertical-align:top to 'img' selector.

```
a {
    background: #999;
    display:inline-block;    
}
a:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
img {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kiran. I choose the answer from nweg because it is a bit more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `a` in css into this...

```
a {
    background: #999; 
    height: 50px; /* height + (padding*2) + (border*2) and also the width*/
    width: 50px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, does it really work? Anyway `position: absolute` is not for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a> is a inline-block;must make it block first.
a {
    background: red;
    display:block;
    width:32px;
}
a:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
img {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px; `
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, it is not an `inline-block` by default. It is `inline`.

Comment: sorry,I mean make <a> become the inline-block;so that it can have its own height and width.

Comment: I know, I just had to mention so no one got confused. ;-)